# Shopify - Can we load script only if page has active Section

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

Is it possible to load the script only when a specific section is active on the page and also if a section is already on the page so the script won't load as many times as the blocks are chosen on the page (for example the are three section so three times the script will be included)

Comment: If you add the script into section code, then it load once the section is active otherwise it doen't.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

1. Add a specific class to your section
2. Write your function in a file loaded with the page
3. Check in JS if the defined specific class exists
4. If it does, execute the function